# Fluid floated element next to fixed-width floated element

Tags: css, css-float

Here's my simple markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col fixed">Short text</div>
  <div class="col fluid">Longer text....</div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.row {
    padding: 20px;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    float: left;
}
.col.fixed {
    width: 200px;
}
```

I thought the fluid text would appear next to the fixed column (to its right), and would then wrap down. This is not what actually happens. Instead, the whole `.col.fluid` drops under the other column, as if there were no floats.

[The demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/7cMQg/1/).

Why doesn't this work (isn't this how floats are supposed to work)? And what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by using this CSS:

```
.row {
    background: rgba(0, 128, 0, .2);
    padding: 20px;
    display:table;
}
.col {
    display:table-cell;
}
.col.fixed {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7cMQg/5/)**

Comment: 1. I'm interested in *why* it's not working (isn't this how floats are supposed to work?). 2. I can't use the table layout engine. This was just a distilled version of what I've got; my real code far too complex to settle for the table layout.

Comment: It would work by using floats if your larger div had a width. Since it doesn't, it expands to as large a width as possible. If you have other restrictions on solutions you should really add them to your question so others don't waste their time.

Comment: OK. I'm accepting your answer, since it answers the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

To get the effect that you want, you need to place the floated-fixed box inside the fluid, block-level div.

See the following: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7cMQg/6/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col fluid">
    <div class="col fixed">Short text: to see the full effect,
    type in a bit more text so that you can get a few lines
    in the floated-fixed-width box.</div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry...
</div>
</div>
```

If you check the CSS, I added a right margin to the floated div and changed the background color to highlight the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like an effect similar to the first letter being larger than the rest of the text (found in many books & writings), try this:

```
<div>
   <span class="fixed">Short text</span>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/7cMQg/7/)